# ListView onItemClick by position

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

I'm trying to make it so when you click row 2 or 4 it runs a different method than the rest of the list items.  The rest go to a website, but I want row 4 to open email, and row 2 to open the navigator.  BUT WHEN I CLICK ON ROW 4, IT OPENS THE BROWSER (i.e. passes the Intent) THEN OPENS THE EMAIL AFTER I BACK OUT. why? --also, navigator force closes but i think its cause the emulator doesn't have navigator installed :/ ANY SUGGESTIONS? THANKS!

getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {final String[] links =getResources().getStringArray(com.BandCustomListView.R.array.ItemLinks);
                @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position,
                    long id){

```
            String positions = links[position];

            if (position == 4){

                final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);


                emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"Mtarpey@worcester.edu"});
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
                ;


                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
            }
             if (position == 2){
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                        Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=127+Southbridge+Street+Auburn+Massachusetts")); 
                        startActivity(i); 
            }
            if (position != (2 | 4)) {

            Intent SendToWebPageView = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebPageView.class);

            SendToWebPageView.setData(Uri.parse(positions));

            startActivity(SendToWebPageView);
            }
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want to change this LOC

if (position != (2 | 4))

To be

if(position != 2 && position != 4)

Since 4 != 2 it will pass that check and kick off the webpage view after you do the check to perform the email intent.